# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/jwt/writer/JwtWriterFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I'm trying to create json web token with the help of `atlassian-jwt` libraries
`jwt-core`, `jwt-api` and `jwt-http-client`
Using this [link](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/understanding-jwt/).

This page has a minimal code for implementing the same.
But getting below error on runtime.

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/jwt/writer/JwtWriterFactory"

JwtWriterFactory jwtWriterFactory = new NimbusJwtWriterFactory();
```

Comment: [Refer this link. It may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: What's the relationship between the error and that line of code?

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually this was version issue.

Comment: Used 1.5.3 version for jwt-api `    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>jwt-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>jwt-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>`